# How to delete sub folder using azure data factory delete activity?

Tags: azure-data-factory

i am able to achieve by using files or delete the entire folders by selecting file path.

But i unable to do delete sub-folder/directory

[image: Reference image]

[image: Reference image 3]

[dataset image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvsqE.png)

[pipeline image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T74gh.png)

delete file is working for me

unable to delete the empty folder(test1,test2)

Could any one help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to check Delete file recursively in Delete Activity Source.

**Delete file recursively** - Delete all files in the input folder and its subfolders recursively or just the ones in the selected folder. This setting is disabled when a single file is selected.

[image]

For more information refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/delete-activity#delete-specific-folders-or-files)

---

Edit -

**Known limitation**

Delete activity does not support deleting list of folders described by wildcard.

When using file attribute filter in delete activity: modifiedDatetimeStart and modifiedDatetimeEnd to select files to be deleted, make sure to set `"wildcardFileName": "*"` in delete activity as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response abhishek. i already tried by checking recursively its delete  files in directory however not an directory. Please find the attached  image in question for your reference

Comment: My usecase is to delete all files inside the folders and delete the folder which is having empty file older than 10 days. when i check recursive its delete files from folders and sub folders but not delete folder or sub folder which is even empty/